# Where does sql server hold the paths of data and log files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, system-databases, master-system-database

Sql server configs (logins/roles/server configs) are stored in masterdb

Jobs/schedules are stored in msdb

Where are the following values stored:

1. Data and log file path of system dbs
2. Data and log file path of user dbs. I want to know this because when I restore master db on another server then it doesn't auto create the user dbs in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Question is tagged with SQL2019 my answer is tested in the same version.

[sys.master_files (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Contains a row per file of a database as stored in the master
> database. This is a single, system-wide view.

For tempdb, view sys.master_files shows initial tempdb size. The values are used as a template for tempdb creation at startup of SQL Server. So, when tempdb grows it is not reflected in the view. To get current size of tempdb files, query tempdb.sys.database_files.

[sys.database_files (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Contains a row per file of a database as stored in the database
> itself. This is a per-database view.

[sys.dm_server_registry (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-server-registry-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

You can get master database data and log file location from here. You can get the same information by opening 'SQL Server Configuration Manager' located at 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc'.

You will find the same information in old system tables and are discouraged by Microsoft to not use those. [Here is a mapping table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) between old system tables and newer system views

Comment: I assume you mean sys.databases contains the paths of users db data/log file? If so then where does it derive this info from?

Comment: I did not mean that. It is a system catalog view named `sys.database_files`. Click the link and it will show you the details. Information is derived from the database itself. Clearly mentioned `as stored in the database itself`.
I see you asked a similar question. Same metadata is also contained in the master database which you can derive from `sys.master_files`.